# (PHP) Object of class SoapClient could not be converted to string

Tags: php, arrays, types, soap-client

This code works fine:

```
$result = $client->__call("optionalInfo", array(
    new SoapParam("...", "client"),
    new SoapParam("...", "add_code"))
);
```

When I try abstracting it a bit to make the script re-usable, I get this error:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class SoapClient could not be converted to string

The broken code is:

```
$params = array( new SoapParam($client, "client"),
             new SoapParam($add_code, "add_code")
);
$result = $client->__call($functionName, $params);
```

The last line is what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want to send the SoapClient interface as an argument to a function call on the same object?

```
new SoapParam($client, "client")
```

Comment: That would be my problem, and no I did not mean to do that.  "Client" happens to be a field for this particular web service and I completely overlooked that.  Thanks!